# gitignore rails neo4j installation?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, git, neo4j, gitignore

Is there anything I want to gitignore in my rails neo4j installation if pushing to a public repo?  I am a newbie at neo4j and I noticed some development private keys under `db/neo4j/development/certificates`. Obviously I would't want to push up my production private key, but will it be ok to push up my development and test keys? In general, should I be pushing up the `db/neo4j/development/` and `db/neo4j/test/` folders or should I expect newcomers to a project to run `rake neo4j:install[edition,environment]`

Answer (score 0):

After a little research I found that this one neo4j rails example does in fact ignore the whole installation:

https://github.com/andreasronge/neo4j-rails-example/blob/master/.gitignore

but it seems like I would not want to ignore the migrations.